# htaccess & Zend Framework passthrough

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess file for my ZF project.

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

# Redirect old site pages
redirect 301 /The_GAPS_Postal_Application_20110126.pdf /pdf/The_GAPS_Postal_Application_20110126.pdf
redirect 301 /The_GAPS_Constitution.pdf /pdf/The_GAPS_Constitution.pdf
redirect 301 /The_GAPS_EJ_Postal_Application_20110126.pdf /pdf/The_GAPS_EJ_Postal_Application_20110126.pdf
redirect 301 /The_GAPS_Fishery_Rules.pdf /pdf/The_GAPS_Fishery_Rules.pdf
redirect 301 "/Gipping Angling and Preservation Society Waters.pdf" /pdf/Gipping_Angling_Preservation_Society_Waters.pdf

redirect 301 /gaps_waters.php /waters
redirect 301 /alderson_lakes.php /waters/alderson-lakes
redirect 301 /barham_b_pit.php /waters/barham-b-pit
redirect 301 /causeway_lakes.php /waters/causeway-lakes
redirect 301 /perch_pit.php /waters/perch-pit
redirect 301 /river_gipping_barham.php /waters/river-gipping-barham
redirect 301 /river_gipping_bramford.php /waters/river-gipping-bramford
redirect 301 /river_gipping_elton_water_bank.php /waters/river-gipping-elton-water-bank
redirect 301 /river_gipping_lagoon.php /waters/river-gipping-shamford-lagoon
redirect 301 /river_gipping_shamford_lock.php /waters/river-gipping-shamford-lock
redirect 301 /river_gipping_sproughton.php /waters/river-gipping-sproughton
redirect 301 /gaps_maps.php /waters/maps
redirect 301 /gaps_rules.php /waters/rules

redirect 301 /joining_gaps.php /membership
redirect 301 /gaps_postal_applications.php /membership/postal-applications
redirect 301 /joining_gaps_early.php /membership/join-early
redirect 301 /joining_caps.php /membership/join-caps
redirect 301 /gaps_guest_permits.php /membership/guest-permits

redirect 301 /gaps_officers.php /officers
redirect 301 /gaps_match_fixtures.php /matches/fixtures
redirect 301 /downloads.php /downloads
redirect 301 /links.php /links
redirect 301 /gaps_work_parties.php /work-parties
redirect 301 /constitution.php /constitution
RewriteEngine On

# Cached files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/*$ cached/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html -f
RewriteRule .* cached/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html [L]

# Route to index.php for ZF
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

# Add compression
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
```

In my public_html folder I have a subfolder called lists containing a third party newsletter application.  However calls to this folder just get redirected to the ZF application.

My question is how do I get the files in the lists folder to pass straight through rather than being directed to the ZF application?

Comment: Make sure the permissions and ownership of the lists directory and files are correct.  If you remove only the `# Route to index.php for ZF` rules, are you able to access the lists application fine?  The ZF rewrite rules look good to me.

Comment: How about something like `RewriteRule ^lists/.*$ - [NC]`?

Comment: @drew010 Looks like the problem was with the htaccess file in the lists sub-directory and not the one above, many thanks